# how to sign in to googleplus using Unofficial Google+ JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have tried to use Unofficial Google+ JavaScript API to post comments but it throws exception "Invalid session, please login to Google+ " while I signed in to googleplus in same browser.

I was referring this help https://github.com/mohamedmansour/google-plus-extension-jsapi
I m using php.
Please help me to login to googlepluse using this API.

Thanks